# ffmpeg module saving not working after compression

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, compression

I'm just trying to save an mp4 to a different mp4 (before I even start playing around with the different compression settings). What exactly is going wrong here?

```
const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');

try {
    var process = new ffmpeg('./original.mp4');
    process.then(function (video) {
        video
        .save('./new.mp4', function (error, file) {
            if (!error) {
                console.log('Video file: ' + file);
            } else {
                console.log(error)
            }
        });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.code);
    console.log(e.msg);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Command failed: ffmpeg -i ./original.mp4  ./new.mp4
/bin/sh: ffmpeg: command not found

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:390:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  killed: false,
  code: 127,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'ffmpeg -i ./original.mp4  ./new.mp4'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the library you're using tries to call an `ffmpeg` executable but cannot find it.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right--I was using this module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg) and I see now that I have to install ffmpeg--but how does something like this work when my app is deployed on Heroku? The executable would normally be installed on the local box, but not sure how that works with a remote deployment...

Comment: I don't have an answer to the Heroku question, sorry.